# What's the CFStringEncoding for Polish?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, localization

A user complained that I don't support Polish character encodings for my iOS app, but I can't seem to figure out what encodings they're looking for.

Comment: Why aren't you using Unicode for everything? You should be. Also, accept answers to some of your previous questions if you want to get good answers to future questions.

Comment: It seems that the user's complaint is that you haven't localized the app to Polish. In that case, the issue is not that of encoding. I hope you are thinking in the right direction.

Comment: I have a text editor, and people complained about not being able to open text files encoded with some "Polish" character encoding. (I did accept the answers to my previous questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [wikipedia page on the Polish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_alphabet):

> The standard 8-bit character encoding for the Polish alphabet is ISO 8859-2 (Latin-2)

To find the CFStringEncoding for Latin-2, [look under External String Encodings here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/External_String_Encodings), to find this information:

```
enum {
    ...
    kCFStringEncodingISOLatin2 = 0x0202
```

**EDIT**: But, as suggested by Jonathan Grynspan, you really should be using Unicode (`kCFStringEncodingUnicode`) for everything.